# Managing an array data structure with concurrent API requests

Tags: node.js, concurrency, microservices

I have a node backend REST API that will be deployed as multiple containers.

I have an array of users = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4'] that can be stored in mongoDb or redis

I have a get endpoint that returns next user from this array.

Eg: for 1st request it should return u1, 2nd request should return u2, 5th request returns u1.

once this API is deployed as multiple containers, Lets say there are 10 containers running and 10 requests are concurrently made, how do I make sure that they are returned in order.

Im looking for a standard approach to handle this scenario. Following is an approach  I have thought of

Store the array as list on redis.

Do LPOP and RPUSH on each request So that list after the first request would be

['u2', 'u3', 'u4', u1]

Concern here is that if 5 requests comes in parallel, there could be a scenario, where 5LPOP could be executed
and array could be empty and RPUSH could be executed out of order.

What is the best approach to handle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Redis you'd need to use MULTI to get a transaction-like behavior

> "All the commands in a transaction are serialized and executed
> sequentially. It can never happen that a request issued by another
> client is served in the middle of the execution of a Redis
> transaction. This guarantees that the commands are executed as a
> single isolated operation" https://redis.io/topics/transactions

note that Redis transactions does not mean strict serializability see https://jepsen.io/analyses/redis-raft-1b3fbf6

Comment: thanks Arnon. If two MULTI transactions are issued by the two different client at the same time. How does this behave?. One client would be executed and 2nd client transaction will be queued untill first client's commands are completed?

Comment: assuming both try to change the same keys the second would fail (since the original values it came out of are no longer valid) - Imaging you have 100$ balance and you have 2 requests to draw 100$ - you need to consider if you really want the second request to go through since the original intention (get 0$ balance) is no longer true (but you can resubmit and get the -100$ if you like) (just an example - I wouldn't run my bank on Redis :) )